# How can I remove the stop words with a non-word boundary?

Tags: java, stop-words

I'm trying to remove a stop word in a txt file using from my stop word list. Some of the stop words are removed bot some are not.

Example this sentence: "it taste nice, doesn’t it?" should have an output like "taste nice" but my code output: "taste nice doesnt it "

my stop word list is from: https://www.ranks.nl/stopwords (Long stop word list).

Here is my code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList sw = new ArrayList<>();

    try{
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("/Users/Dan/Desktop/DATA/stopwords.txt");

        byte b[] = new byte[fis.available()];
        fis.read(b);
            fis.close();

            String data[] = new String(b).split("\n");

        for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
        {
            sw.add(data[i].trim());
        }
         FileInputStream fis2 = new FileInputStream("/Users/Dan/Desktop/DATA/cleandata.txt");

        byte bb[] = new byte[fis2.available()];
        fis2.read(bb);
            fis2.close();

            String data2[] = new String(bb).split("\n");



            for(int i = 0; i < data2.length; i++)

        {
            String file = "";
            String s[] = data2[i].split("\\s");
            for(int j = 0; j < s.length; j++)
            {
                if(!(sw.contains(s[j].trim().toLowerCase())))
                {
                    file=file + s[j] + " ";
                }

            }
            file = file.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z\\s+]", "");

            System.out.println(file.replaceAll("\\s+", " ").toLowerCase() + "\n");

        }

    } catch(Exception a){
        a.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

What should I do? I think I have a problem in printing

```
file = file.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z\\s+]", "");

System.out.println(file.replaceAll("\\s+", " ").toLowerCase() + "\n");
```

Comment: You have "doesnt" instead of "doesn’t" in your stop list?

Comment: I have doesn't.

Comment: Please, please, please! Don't ever write code like this. Use meaningful names, extract methods for coherent, high-level steps of your algorithm, extract constants for String literals and other fixed values. Make this a habit always. Don't ever write shitty code, not even when it's 'just an example'. If you always write readable code you are training your eyes and mind so it becomes second nature and effortless and you will be doing yourself and everybody else who has to read your code a favor.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I'm not really good in making code. I'll make it more readable next time.

Comment: When you split your `cleandata.txt` you got `it?` instead of `it`. Your `stopwords.txt` contains only `it`. That `doesn’t` part isn't removed because of different `'` character. In your example you are using `’` but in `stopwords.txt`. you have `'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different quote characters being used. The stopwords file contains `doesn't` and your input contains `doesn’t`.

Because the quotes are different, the words don't match.

EDIT: Here's a slightly refactored solution which generates the correct output (if you don't use weird quotes in the input that is).

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class StopWordsApp {

    // the platform-specific end of line token
    private static final String EOL = String.format("%n");

    private final Set<String> stopWords = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(readLines("stopwords.txt")));

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StopWordsApp stopWordsApp = new StopWordsApp();
        String[] lines = readLines("cleandata.txt");
        printLines(stopWordsApp.removeStopWords(lines));
    }

    private String[] removeStopWords(String[] inputLines) {
        return Arrays.stream(inputLines)
                // map the String array to a Line object
                .map(Line::new)
                // map the Line to a String without stop words
                .map(this::removeStopWords)
                // convert the stream to an array
                .toArray(String[]::new);
    }

    private String removeStopWords(Line line) {
        return line.words().stream()
                // map the word to its normalized version
                .map(Word::normalized)
                // remove stop words
                .filter(n -> !stopWords.contains(n))
                // join into a String separated by spaces
                .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
    }

    private static String[] readLines(String fileName) {
        return readFile(fileName).split(EOL);
    }

    private static String readFile(String fileName) {
        return new Scanner(StopWordsApp.class.getResourceAsStream(fileName), "UTF-8").useDelimiter("\\A").next();
    }

    private static void printLines(String[] lines) {
        for (String line : lines) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
}
```

I extracted separate classes for a Line:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Line {

    private final List<Word> words;

    public Line(String input) {
        String[] wordInputs = input.split("\\s+");
        words = Arrays.stream(wordInputs)
                // remove empty Strings
                .filter(v -> !v.isEmpty())
                // map String to a Word object
                .map(Word::new)
                // collect into a List
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public List<Word> words() {
        return words;
    }

}
```

..and for a Word:

```
public class Word {

    private final String normalized;

    public Word(String input) {
        normalized = input
                // convert to lower case
                .toLowerCase()
                // remove everything that's not a lower case letter or a quote
                // (the stopwords file only contains lower case letters and quotes)
                .replaceAll("[^a-z']", "")
                // replace consecutive white space with a single space
                .replaceAll("\\s+", " ")
                // trim any white space at the edges
                .trim();
    }

    public String normalized() {
        return normalized;
    }

}
```

... and a custom (runtime) exception:

```
public class StopWordsException extends RuntimeException {
    public StopWordsException(Exception e) {
        super(e);
    }
}
```

I used Java 8 streams everywhere and added comments to explain what's going on.

With the input:

`it  Taste nice,   doesn't     it?`

The output is:

`taste nice`

P.S. The files 'stopwords.txt' and 'cleandata.txt' need to be in the same package as the StopWordsApp class.

Comment: ' is not the same as ’

Comment: I appreciate your help sir. it works now. thank you so much. I'll keep your advice!